# Error in CalendarView

Tags: android, xml

I am implementing a `CalendarView`,i'm getting error as

```
02-12 11:18:39.792: E/Trace(6459): error opening trace file: No such file or directory   
(2)02-12 11:19:29.251: E/dalvikvm-heap(6459): Out of memory on a 5242896-byte
allocation.02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  
activity ComponentInfo{com.docket/com.docket.NHome}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable  
to start activity ComponentInfo{com.docket/com.docket.Home}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class    
android.widget.CalendarView
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.docket/com.docket.Home}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class 
android.widget.CalendarView
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at  
  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   at 
  android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
   02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):  at 
  com.docket.Home.onCreate(Home.java:23)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   at 
  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   at 
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   ... 21 more
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): Caused by:  
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):  at 
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):   at 
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    ... 38 more
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
```

my xml code is,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <CalendarView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/calender"       
                android:background="@drawable/cbg"

                />

            </LinearLayout>             
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no CalendarView on device with API < 11

Comment: and why are you using two namespaces `android1` and `android2` pointing the same schema?

Comment: Please add more logcat, there's the root "caused by" exception below.

Comment: @Ramya can you post full error stack trace... and remember `CalendarView` is added in API level 11.

Comment: @Ramya consider using nine-patch image as background for `CalendarView`...

Comment: @GopalRao I got it..Thank you..it's because of my background image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-12 11:19:30.041: E/AndroidRuntime(6459):     at 
 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
```

Out of memory decoding bitmap resources. Likely the background drawable you set to the `CalendarView` is too large. Replace it with a smaller resolution image that takes less memory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your same code and is working properly.You just need to change the minimum API level in your manifest to 11.As `CalendarView` supports on device with API >11

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: thank you..but i have given my minSdkVersion as 14, same error remains..Is there any changes to be done in emulator properties?

Comment: yes.I have changed the background.Rest of the code is same..:)